# Making my Flutter app simply say "Hellooo!" when launched

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

Absolute, absolute noob here.

So all I am trying to do here is just get the app to say "Hellooo!" when launched. I am a bit stuck here, very new to Flutter/Dart.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: 'Testing',
      home: HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class HomeScreen {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Column(children: [Text('Helloooo!')],
    )
  )
}
```

I keep trying to follow different tutorials and copy the layouts of each sample code. I am not sure what I am missing. For **return**, it gives me a message "Expected a class member.
Try placing this code inside a class member."

Answer (score 3):

You need to extend the widget, on simple case, extend the `StatelessWidget` or `StatefulWidget`.

`home:` expect widget, not class.

```dart
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: [Text('Helloooo!')]);
  }
}
```

> Every class isn't a widget.

I will recommend to check [widgets-intro](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/widgets-intro).
You can find more on [.flutter.dev/cookbook](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook)

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! Have a virtual cookie: U+1F36A

Comment: Glad to help. Make sure to check those link for better understanding.